# Exhibit a countable collection of open sets $U_j$ such that each open set can be written as a union of some of the sets $U_j$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Exhibit a countable collection of open sets $U_j$ such that each open set $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ can be written as a union of some of the sets $U_j$.

I'm having trouble with this one. If I'm reading this, any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ including disjoint sets and those involving irrational numbers would need to be written as a union of sets from $U_j$. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Not sure if that's possible. Consider that there are uncountably many open sets. For each one of those uncountably many open sets we would need some collection of subsets $U_j$ whose union was a specific open set belonging to the collection of all opens sets; implying that the number of sets $U_j$ required to account for all open sets is $\geq$ the number of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the collection of open intervals $(a,b)$ for all $a<b$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.